# How can I iterate through a list in python more efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that returns the greatest prime factor of any given number. The code works for relatively small numbers, but once they start getting bigger, it takes forever for the code to run.

```py
memo = {}

def is_prime(n):
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = True
        for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                memo[n] = False
                return False
    return memo[n]


def prime_factors(n):
    factors = []
    prime_factor = []
    for i in range(n, 2, -1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    for num in factors:
            if is_prime(num):
                prime_factor.append(num)
                break
    print(prime_factor)

prime_factors()
```

Is there anyway to make this more efficient, I think it has something to do with the fact that I am referring to another function within prime_factors function which is causing it to be very inefficient.

Comment: Referring to other functions isn't the cause of inefficiency

Comment: Yep. He also registers every bit of integer in the `memo` dictionary to keep track of prime numbers - which is not necessary.

Comment: You need a better algorithm to make it go faster. Yes the list approach in your code is slower because there are unnecessary numbers generated for the list. If you are running this repeatedly, you could first create a list of prime numbers up to the square root of the maximum input number. Take a look into Miller Rabin Prime factorization for extremely fast approaches when the input numbers are very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't quite understand your approach, especially why you always start to calculate in the `is_prime(n)` function from the beginning, which increases the complexity on large inputs considerably. Also the `for num in factors:` part in your `prime_factors(n)` function doesn't make much sense to me.

However you can try this solution instead:

```
import time


def get_next_prime(n: int = 0):
    if n < 1:
        return 2

    if 1 <= n < 3:
        return n + 1

    while True:
        n += 1

        # Corner cases
        if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
            continue

        i = 5
        not_prime = False
        # check till sqrt(n) because a larger factor of n must be
        # a multiple of smaller factor that has been already checked.
        while i * i <= n:
            if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
                not_prime = True
                break

            i = i + 6

        if not_prime:
            continue

        return n


def prime_factors(dividend):
    # dividend : divisor = quotient (remainder)
    divisor = get_next_prime()
    quotient = -1

    factors = []

    while quotient != 0:
        remainder = dividend % divisor
        quotient = dividend // divisor

        if remainder == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
            dividend = quotient
        else:
            divisor = get_next_prime(divisor)

    return factors

start = time.time()
print(prime_factors(899999999998))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Check out this demo: https://repl.it/repls/DefiantRecursiveWamp

---

About the algorithm which is in place, consider this example:

Terminology: 
`dividend : divisor = quotient (remainder)`

i.e. 7 : 2 = 3 (1)

Problem: Find out the prime factors of **18**

1. Initial

   - Get the next prime number for `divisor`: which is **2**
2. `18 : 2 = 9 (0)`

   - remainder 0
   - Take **2** and update `dividend`
3. `9  : 2 = 4 (1)`

   - remainder is **NOT** 0
   - Get the **next** prime number for `divisor`: which is **3**; `dividend` remains untouched
4. `9  : 3 = 3 (0)`

   - remainder 0
   - Take **3** and update `dividend`
5. `3  : 3 = 1 (0)`

   - remainder 0
   - Take **3** and update `dividend`
6. `1  : 3 = 0 (0)`

   - The `quotient` is **0** -> stop!

Prime factors: `{2, 3, 3}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).
and in-built map, filter functions